# Faking and injecting cryptographic certificates

Tags: certificates, injection

Suppose as an attacker I provide a fake certificate to a user.A warning pops up on her window but she decides to continue anyways.Is my fake certificate now added in her browser's trusted certificate list? If she tries to visit my website and I provide the fake certificate again is she warned again or not? Also,how can I inject a fake certificate in a target's list of certificates so that she is not shown a warning certificate?

Comment: Certificates needs to be manually added to the trusted list. Always. It may be checked as a default option in some browsers when checking the error details.

Comment: I find that it actually depends on the browser - Chrome's behavior differs from Firefox in this regard. In Chrome, the certificate is NOT marked trusted, and the warning will continue to pop up unless the user goes through an elaborate sequence of steps to manually add it to the trusted certificate list. In Firefox, the user cannot proceed without adding a "Security Exception" for the site, after which the user will no longer see warnings.

Comment: You're asking how to break SSL via a remote attack. It really isn't that easy.

Comment: @NeilSmithline If you don't care about warnings popping up and you're on the same network as the target, it's actually quite easy to perform an MITM attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my fake certificate now added in her browser's trusted certificate list?

Yes, depending on the browser being used. It used to be that ALL browsers behaved this way. Adding a self signed certificate to the trusted certificate store.

> If she tries to visit my website and I provide the fake certificate again is she warned again or not?

In the last few years this behavior was modified to force acceptance of the non signed certificate prior to proceeding to better protect unsavy internet users from falling victim to this sort of exploit.

> Also,how can I inject a fake certificate in a target's list of certificates so that she is not shown a warning certificate?

While this area of research (using a cluster of devices to brute force and factor a collision of the random number generator leading to a private key with which to generate a weakly signed x.509 certificate) has provided fruitful results in labs, it is not common, and very computationally expensive to do.

In order for you to 'inject a fake certificate' that would evade the browsers OSCP stapling you must have a valid signed X.509 certificate from a CA (certificate authority).